# How to retrieve User Information List data

Tags: sharepoint-designer, filter, caml-query, visual-studio

I would like to filter a list based upon a user group that the user may belong to and a specific value found in the User Information List for that user.

I tried doing this with CAML in SharePoint Designer but was not able to retrieve a value from the User Information List based upon the current user.  (I was able to filter by the user group though.)

I found a tool that did a lookup on this list, but it required WSS 3.0 and I am running SharePoint Foundation.

Can I do a lookup on certain field in the User Information List for the logged in user and store that value in a variable in Sharepoint Designer?  Will I need to use VS?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 has 'binding redirects' that make WSS 3.0/MOSS 2007 code think it is running on that older platform. Have you tried ignoring the tool's requirements and running it anyway? It may work.

Comment: Hi Alex,

It wont install unless I have WSS 3.0.  Thank you for all your previous help today.

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use javascript and the web services to get this info? That is how I get data from the user info list for the current user. There is also a jQuery library that makes it even easier [here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hi spevilgenius.  I tried this but had problems with ajax.  Can I do what you suggested while running Sharepoint foundation?  I tried to follow this example: http://www.midnightprogrammer.net/post/Calling-ASPNET-Web-Service-Using-Jquery-Part-I.aspx

Thanks again.
Richard

Comment: I personally have not used foundation yet, but I do know that the SPServices library works in it. There is a lot of information at the http://spservices.codeplex.com site.

Comment: Hi spevilgenius.  I am learning about client side classes from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx.  Do you know how to get lookup fields to show their id value?  Thank you.

Richard

Comment: Lookup values are stored in a somewhat strange format: id;#value If you are getting this value in javascript, you can get the value as a string and then split that string on the ; character. The resulting array will have two parts like array[0] = id and array[1] = #value and you could also split that last one if you want the value as well. Hopefully this gets you going!